# Rename worksheets' names from an .xls file

Tags: python, excel

I am creating an .xls file by converting two .csv files and joining them by following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
from pandas import ExcelWriter

def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
    writer = ExcelWriter(xls_path)
    for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
         df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % n,index = False)
    writer.save()

save_xls((df,df1), "path/test.xls")
```

Of course I am creating dataframes df and df1 by reading two CSVs. And in path I am getting the joined .xls single file with two sheets (windows).

But the worksheets names are `sheet0` and `sheet1` like this. My requirement is how to rename those sheets to `name1` and `name2`.

i have tried passing a name tuple to it but throws error.

```
name = 'event','segment'

df.to_excel(writer,name,index = False)  #inside function block

#AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

also tried to split the name tuple inside to_excel line:

```
df.to_excel(writer,name.split(","),index = False)

#AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

So is there a way to rename those worksheets' names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
name = 'event','segment'
for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
    df.to_excel(writer,name[n],index = False)  #inside function block
```